# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor`

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting a very weird error when I am trying to Build an input pipeline with tf.data. I am combining my reference image  and my drawing into a tuple. Then I added to  that to list. This should work,

but now I am getting this weird error at this line:

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Here is my code:

```
@tf.function()
def load_image_train(a_training_datapoint):
 print(type(a_training_datapoint))
 print("here 1")
 real_image_path, drawing_path = zip(*a_training_datapoint)
 print("here 2")
 real_image = convert_images_to_tensor(real_image_path)
 print("here 3")
 drawing_image = convert_images_to_tensor(drawing_path)
 real_image, drawing_image = random_jitter(real_image, drawing_image)
 real_image, drawing_image = normalize(real_image, drawing_image)
return real_image, drawing_image
```

and then I have this:

```
test_dataset_list = []
for data in test_set:
 test_dataset_list.append(zip(data.reference_image, data.drawing))
print(test_dataset_list)
```

Here 1 is the only one that prints out.

so it seem to not like how I am unzipping my tuple, but I am sure I am doing it right.

Also it say this :
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

when I am printing out the type for the a_test_datapoint

Comment: Why do you decorate this function with `@tf.function()` ? I think you should remove it

Comment: @ Andrzejo, I was just trying to get it to work, so  I was trying different things

Answer (score -1):

This Zip method is not zip as file encryption but it is reference mapping you cannot read it as some of the hardware trying but the object still exists if not it cannot revert back-references.

The same problem you working on with routing paths or simulation problems I sample as game find next actions and exists to solutions.

Server - hardware security tasks, one roles why zip Fn

Try it and see the working loggs.

Sample: Zip for over-lapping work input text sequences.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tft

input_word = tf.constant(' \'Cause it\'s easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Oh, easy as an ice cream sundae ' )

print( 'input_word: ' + str(input_word) )
print( " " )

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word ) )


window_size = 6
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tft.sliding_window(x, width=window_size, axis=0) ).flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
print( dataset )

test_dataset_list = []
icount = 0
for data in dataset:
    test_dataset_list.append(zip(tf.constant(data, name=str(icount)), tf.constant(data, name=str(icount + 1))))
    icount = icount + 1
print(test_dataset_list)
```

Comment: @ Jirayu Kaewprateep, I do not understand what you are doing, can you put it in term of what I am trying to to ?